# How do I add didSet to view property of UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In my `UIViewController`, I would like to add code as soon as my view property is set:

```
var view:UIView! {
    didSet {
        //(view as MyView).delegate ...
    }
}
```

Obviously, it doesn't work because I cannot override variable of super class.

Is there any workaround to achieve what I want?

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view will be set just once, and at that time `viewDidLoad` will be called. So go with the flow and override `viewDidLoad` and set the delegate there.